# how to set my eclipse to make it can import the package automatically?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am a new bee of java, today I use eclipse to develop an android application,I need to use some function,but I don't know their packages,I know eclipse can import the package automatically,how to set it to enable this function?

Comment: whenever you use certain functionality from another package, Eclipse should recognize it and hint to import the package.

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965918/prevent-eclipse-from-auto-import-packages-when-copying-source-code-between-proje).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Go to menu -> Source -> Organize Imports

or simply use the shortcut

> Ctrl+Shift+O

Comment: Or ctrl+1 if you want to se what it imports.

Answer (score 1):

```
Ctrl + Shift + O
```

Should do the job.